# Authenticating a Vue 2 Azure Static Web App Locally Against Auth0

Tags: azure, vue.js, vuejs2, auth0, azure-static-web-app

I am researching the feasibility of porting an existing Vue 2 app to be an Azure Static Web App (SWA). A requirement is the ability to run the Vue app locally and authenticate against our Auth0 tenant to retrieve a access/bearer token to send along with our HTTP requests.

It appears that a SWA can utilize [custom authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad) (Auth0), and I was able to complete that successfully by following [this article](https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2021-05-13-using-auth0-with-static-web-apps/). However, I'm not seeing any information around capturing the access token. There is an `/.auth/me/` endpoint which has user information, but that does not contain the access token:

[image]

I also looked into the [Azure Static Web App Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/local-development#authorization-and-authentication-emulation) which allows for defining an identity profile when running locally, but I'm not seeing a way to specify an access token here either.

Is it possible at the moment with a SWA to obtain an access token using a custom auth provider when running locally and when published live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed Authentication in Azure is really only useful for fairly simple use cases. I think you're going to want to implement your security directly inside your Vue application.

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login

You mentioned needing an access token but didn't say where it comes from or what you're doing with it. Are you trying to call an Auth0-secured API?

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/02-calling-an-api

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was under the impression that with Azure Static Web Apps it was **required** to utilize the provided security mechanisms. The route I was going down didn't use one of the built-in managed provided registrations. I was attempting to override that with a custom registration as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom). But what I think you are saying is I am able to just bypass all of that at implement a custom implementation?

Comment: Yes. I'm not familiar with the overrides but I don't see you it will allow you to request an access token.